# Como evitar doble submit al ejecutar AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Dentro de mi aplicación lo que intento lograr es primero capturar un dato desde un input tipo texto y después ejecutar a AJAX para el envio del resto de los datos del formulario sin necesidad de un boton de enviar y de manera automática, ya que utilizo una condición para ejecutar el ajax, al ejecutar esto, en algunas ocasiones se repite el envió y me aparecen datos repetidos.

```
function proceso(){
if(long.length != 8){
   document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Introduce los " + a + " 
caracteres restantes";
   if(a==1){
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Introduce el caracter 
restante";
   }
   else if(a==8){
       document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "";
   }

  }
    else{
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Captura exitosa, se ha 
      registrado el producto";

  $(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'save-productos.php',
      data: $('#form1').serialize(),
      datatype: JSON,
      success: function (data) {
       // alert(data);
      }
    });
});
    }
}
```

php

```
 <?php 
        include 'dbh.php';

        $codigo = $_POST['nombreproducto'];
        $numeroLote = $_POST['numlotes'];
        $fechaE = $_POST['fechaE'];
        $date1 = date('y-m-d', strtotime($fechaE));
        $fechaC = $_POST['fechaC'];
        $date2 = date('y-m-d', strtotime($fechaC));
        $numlot = $_POST['nlote'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE 
 codigo_de_producto=\"".$codigo."\"";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      /*   $sqllotes = "SELECT * FROM lotes ORDER BY no_de_lote DESC LIMIT 
 1";
         $resultlotes = mysqli_query($conn, $sqllotes);
         $rowlotes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultlotes);
         $datos = $rowlotes['no_de_lote'] + 1;
         */
         $num = 1;
         $cont = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($cont==0){
            $sql7 = "INSERT INTO producto 
 (id,nombre_de_producto,codigo_de_producto) VALUES 
 (DEFAULT,'palomitas',\"".$codigo."\")";
            $sql8 = "INSERT INTO lotes 
 (no_de_lote,tamano_de_lote,elementos_involucrados) VALUES 
 (\"".$numlot."\",\"".$numeroLote."\",\"".$codigo."\")";
            $sql9 = "INSERT INTO fechas 
 (codigo_de_producto,fecha_de_elaboracion,fecha_de_caducidad,lote) VALUES 
 (\"".$codigo."\",\"".$date1."\",\"".$date2."\",\"".$numlot."\")";
            $sql10 = "INSERT INTO estado 
 (codigoprod,en_almacen,en_tienda,regresado,caducado,vendido) VALUES 
 (\"".$codigo."\",\"".$num."\",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql7);
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql8);
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql9);
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql10);

        }
        else if($cont > 0)  {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM fechas WHERE 
 codigo_de_producto=\"".$row['codigo_de_producto']."\"";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
                $miFecha = date('y-m-d');
                $miFecha2 = $row2['fecha_de_caducidad'];
                $time2 = date('y-m-d', strtotime($miFecha2));
                $time1 = strtotime($miFecha);
                $time3 = strtotime($time2);
               /* echo $time1;
                echo ",";
                echo $time3;*/
                if($time1>=$time3){
                    //caducado
                    $sql3 = "UPDATE estado SET caducado = 1 WHERE 
codigoprod=\"".$row['codigo_de_producto']."\"";
                    $sql4 = "UPDATE estado SET en_tienda = NULL WHERE 
codigoprod=\"".$row['codigo_de_producto']."\"";
                    $sql11 = "UPDATE estado SET regresado = 1 WHERE 
codigoprod=\"".$row['codigo_de_producto']."\"";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql11); 

                }
                else{
                    // almacen y regresado
                    $sqlrevisar = "SELECT * FROM estado WHERE 
codigoprod=\"".$row['codigo_de_producto']."\"";
                    $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlrevisar);
                    $rw = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
                    if($rw['en_tienda'] == 1){
                    $sql5 = "UPDATE estado SET en_almacen = 1 WHERE 
codigoprod=\"".$row['codigo_de_producto']."\"";
                    $sql12 = "UPDATE estado SET en_tienda = NULL WHERE 
codigoprod=\"".$row['codigo_de_producto']."\"";
                    $sql6 = "UPDATE estado SET regresado = 1 WHERE 
codigoprod=\"".$row['codigo_de_producto']."\"";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql5);
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql6);
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql12);
                    }

                }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Lo primero que te recomendaría es que trates de incluir un mejor contexto de tu código, ya que pueden haber muchos factores por los cuales se esté realizando la doble petición al servidor. Con un contexto más amplio de lo que ya has tecleado nos ayudarías a analizar qué es lo que está causando el error.

Comment: lo que generalmente se hace es crear un efecto loading (cargando...) y dicho efecto esta sobre toda tu pagina y no te deja hacer nada hasta que termine tu ajax...

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias formas de hacer eso que quieres, en tu funcion ajax agregas un `beforeSend` para decirle q bloquee algunos elementos del formulario enviado, quedaria asi:

```
    $(function () {
            $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: 'save-productos.php',
              data: $('#form1').serialize(),
              datatype: JSON,
              beforeSend: function () {
                //aki usas el id de tus elementos para bloquearlos antes de hacer submit
                $('#id-de-boton-submit').attr('class', 'disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
                $('body').attr('style', 'cursor:wait')
                $('#id-de-tu-formulario').css("opacity", ".5");
              },
              success: function (data) {
               // alert(data);
               //luego de los resultados vuelve los elementos a su estado normal
                $('#id-de-boton-submit').attr('class', 'btn btn-primary').removeAttr('disabled')
                $('body').attr('style', 'cursor:default')
                $('#id-de-tu-formulario').css("opacity", "");
              }
            });
        });
            }
        }
```

Espero que sea de tu ayuda.